# How to change the root of a clientspec using cmd

Tags: client, set, perforce, root

I have created a new clientspec using the command :

> `p4 client abc;`

abc is the name of my cs

Now I want to change the root of this cs.

Can somebody please tell that how can I change the root of this clientspec without explicitly modifying the client file.(i.e. by using some command).
And is there any option of mentioning the root path while creating or setting the client (through command line)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some tips:

When creating a client a new client spec, you can seed the Root field by using the -d global option, e.g.:

```
p4 -d /this/is/the/client/root client NewClientName
```

You can also pipe the output of 'p4 client -o' to 'p4 client -i' to create or modify a client spec without having to open an editor, e.g.:

```
p4 -d /this/is/the/client/root client -o NewClientName | p4 client -i
```

The `p4 -d` trick won't do anything to replace the Root field in an existing client spec, however. For that, you need an inline filter, something like this:

```
p4 client -o ExistingClientName | sed -e '/Root:/ s,.*,Root: /new/root/path,' | p4 client -i
```

Comment: This is perhaps what i was looking for. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This is how your change  root of an existing client spec using PowerShell script

```
$p4ClientSpec = p4 client -o "$env:COMPUTERNAME" 
$p4ClientSpec = $p4ClientSpec -replace '^Root:.+$', "Root: D:\test" 
$p4ClientSpec | p4 client -i
```

Comment: When I did this I had to remove the $env;computername in the first line to get it to work. "p4 client -o" was all I needed. After that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

My setup:

- macOS 10.14
- p4 2019.1

None of the existing answers work for me.

I had to run in the Terminal

```
p4 client my-client
```

to edit the root path right in the opened text editor and save the spec.

After that, all is OK.